# Spivak, chapter 6. question 2. Determine for which $x$ a function is continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

As a part of this problem I am supposed to determine when the function

$f(x) = \left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  0,\quad 1 \text{ never appears in the decimal expansion of } x \\
        n,\quad 1 \text{ first appears in the nth place in the decimal expansion of } x\
 \end{array}
\right.$

is continuous. This is how I've tried:

If $f(a) = 0$ then $f$ can't be continuous on $a$  because $\lim_{x\to a}f(x) \neq 0$ if it exists. This is because no matter the $\delta$ there is always some number $m = 0.00000...0000d < \delta$, such that adding $m$ to $x$ will result in $x$ having a $1$ in its decimal expansion and thereby making $|f(x) - 0| > \epsilon$ for $\epsilon < 1$.

On the other hand, if $f(a) = n$ then I thought that as long as the decimal expansion of $x$ does not end in $19999...$ or $10000...$ there will always be some number $m, \quad |m|< \delta$ such that adding $m$ to $a$ will only affect some decimal(s) after the first $1$, and thereby keeping $f(x) = f(a+m) = f(a)$. This should not be the case if decimal expansion of $x$ ends with $19999...$ or $10000...$ because then there is always some $m, |m| < \delta$ such that adding $m$ to $a$ will alter the position of the first $1$. But according to the book's answer $f$ is continuous for all $x$ with a $1$ in its decimal expansion, even those ending with $19999...$ or $10000...$. How can this be?

Comment: Either such expansions were ruled out, or it's a mistake.

Comment: Ok, such expansions were not ruled out in the questions before so I guess it is a mistake.